# Invalid grant on SAML2 Bearer Assertion profile for OAuth within WSO2 API Manager

Tags: oauth, wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have problems getting work "SAML2 Bearer Assertion profile for Oauth" within WSO2 API Manager(9445 port).

**My Setup,**

1. I created an application (app1) in API manager tenant domain (wso2.com) and generated keys.
2. When I log into IS as admin of wso2.com tenant domain I see a service provider is created for my application (app1).
3. I configured the SP of app1 and created the IDP as explained in [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/SAML+Extension+Grant).
4. I could generate SAML assertion by SAML2AssertionCreator.
5. When I try to generate access token using the assertion generated with command I get "
   {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Provided Authorization Grant is invalid"}

SAML Assertion

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml:Assertion
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="alajckjphcbadkfhacmcfnnanohlnlpbhfomlmjm" IssueInstant="2017-06-13T08:05:36.500Z" Version="2.0">
    <saml:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">TestSP</saml:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature
        xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <ds:Reference URI="#alajckjphcbadkfhacmcfnnanohlnlpbhfomlmjm">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces
                            xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="ds saml xs xsi"/>
                        </ds:Transform>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>ISNhVVsEbeRLN2MQdob0qs1QEXc=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>
XrMqLJO6z8BERlmrysn9aV9m1GPte3hOUqxNUhr8eTMtho2zjYE5fJkbT+pf8oHxXUaozefs5G+o
N0tWQc9pqXxuYtk6Lk/EimMzF2xEgrtEzZqksVebJagz9UeOr1mfubZpSGcfdWMHSJdkOuAmsW0E
rqIc1RZDh+95aoh3VmE=
</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>MIICNTCCAZ6gAwIBAgIES343gjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBVMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzELMAkGA1UE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=</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">admin</saml:NameID>
            <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="0" NotOnOrAfter="2017-06-13T08:10:36.500Z" Recipient="https://localhost:9445/oauth2/token"/>
            </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2017-06-13T08:05:36.500Z" NotOnOrAfter="2017-06-13T08:10:36.500Z">
            <saml:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml:Audience>https://localhost:9445/oauth2/token</saml:Audience>
            </saml:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml:Conditions>
        <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2017-06-13T08:05:36.601Z">
            <saml:AuthnContext>
                <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml:AuthnContext>
        </saml:AuthnStatement>
        <saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:Attribute Name="C">
                <saml:AttributeValue
                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">:
                </saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
        </saml:AttributeStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
```

Command `java -jar SAML2AssertionCreator.jar TestSP admin https://localhost:9445/oauth2/token https://localhost:9445/oauth2/token .../wso2/wso2is-5.1.0/repository/resources/security/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks wso2carbon wso2carbon wso2carbon`

Token CMD-

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer&assertion=<Assertion_provided_by_client>&scope=PRODUCTION" -H "Authorization: Basic <Base64 encoded consumer key:consumer secret>" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://<IP of the APIM server>:9445/oauth2/token
```

Logs

```
[2017-06-13 12:56:17,036] DEBUG - OAuth2Service Access Token request received for Client ID 0rD1Hf7ZT5ZMz5ZJkMDpCZSBOHka, User ID null, Scope : [PRODUCTION] and Grant Type : urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer
[2017-06-13 12:56:17,036] DEBUG - AbstractClientAuthHandler Can authenticate with client ID and Secret. Client ID: 0rD1Hf7ZT5ZMz5ZJkMDpCZSBOHka
[2017-06-13 12:56:17,039] DEBUG - AbstractClientAuthHandler Grant type : urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer Strict client validation set to : null
[2017-06-13 12:56:17,043] DEBUG - OAuth2Util Client credentials were available in the cache for client id : 0rD1Hf7ZT5ZMz5ZJkMDpCZSBOHka
[2017-06-13 12:56:17,045] DEBUG - OAuth2Util Successfully authenticated the client with client id : 0rD1Hf7ZT5ZMz5ZJkMDpCZSBOHka
[2017-06-13 12:56:17,055] DEBUG - SAML2BearerGrantHandler SAML Assertion Audience Restriction validation failed against the Audience : https://192.168.0.4:9445/oauth2/token of Identity Provider : IS in tenant : carbon.super
[2017-06-13 12:56:17,055] DEBUG - AccessTokenIssuer Invalid Grant provided by the client Id: 0rD1Hf7ZT5ZMz5ZJkMDpCZSBOHka
[2017-06-13 12:56:17,060] DEBUG - AccessTokenIssuer OAuth-Error-Code=invalid_grant client-id=0rD1Hf7ZT5ZMz5ZJkMDpCZSBOHka grant-type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer scope=PRODUCTION
```

Comment: can someone help me out? @farasath

Comment: Any help is appreciated.

Comment: according to the debug log audience restriction validation has failed. Check this discussion to solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41817168/wso2am-saml-provided-authorization-grant-is-invalid